# How should I create my Kotlin multi-module project with Intellij Idea?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, android-jetpack-compose, multi-module

I want to create a Kotlin project with Gradle as a build tool that has 3 modules:

- A `core` module that contains the "business logic" (the entities that I will use and all the stuff I need to implement the logic of my app) used by the other modules
- A `cli` module that uses picocli to create a command line utility
- A `desktop` module that uses Jetpack Compose for Desktop to build the UI

Is this a use case for Kotlin Multiplatform?
What (and how) can I do with some kind of wizard and what do I have to do by hand?
And if not Kotlin Multiplatform, how do I setup the whole thing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this very much is a use case for Kotlin Multiplatform.

In IntelliJ use the menu to create a new project and select "Kotlin Multiplatform App". That will create the basic structure for you.  After that, study study study.